# MPD: receive actual mpd-status with Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, mpd

I want to know how to receive the actual status of the mpd player with a linux bash script. I know how to start and stop the player...

```
#!/bin/bash
mpc play
mpc volume +1
mpc stop
```

...but i need to know if mpd is playing a song or not. Also the current volume setting is interesting.

I tried to receive it with `mpcstatus=cat /var/tmp/mpd_status` or `actvol=cat /var/tmp/mpd_volume` but the files do not exist. I'm working with [Volumio](http://www.volumio.com/)/Debian on a RaspberryPi.

Comment: `mpc status` does not work, it gives just `volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off` ,no matter whether it's playing or not. Only the volume can be extracted from that string.

Comment: `mpc status` giving those results in all cases sounds like a bug. Have you looked at the `mpc`'s developer site and or bug list. Maybe it fixed in a beta? Maybe they would take a bug report. Good luck!

Comment: I have to apologise! `mpc status` is displaying the following: `Atomic Rooster - Time Take My Life
[playing] #1/18   0:00/5:59 (0%)
volume: 75%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off`. Seems to bee that I just checked the output when the player was stopped! Now it should be easy to filter the needed values with the grep-command.

Comment: Not really a complete answer to this question, but mpc does have a `current` command.  As far as I can tell, if `mpc current` produces no output, then mpd is not playing.  This helps with the "if mpd is playing a song or not" part.  It does nothing to help with "current volume setting".

Answer (score 3):

I've got it!

Play:

```
if mpc status | grep playing >/dev/nul      # If mpd is playing
then
 command... 
fi
```

Volume:

```
ACTVOL=`mpc status | sed -n '/volume/p' | cut -c8-10 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'`
```

Comment: This won't work if any of those keywords is located in currently playing song title. You should parse only the line containing your information:
`if mpc status | awk 'NR==2' | grep playing; then [...]`